# Execution time for multple INSERT in phpMyAdmin wampserver 2.2

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, wampserver

I have installed wampserver in my machine. In phpMyAdmin, I created a database and a table inside it. I need to INSERT values to the table and measure time for queries. When I run a single INSERT like below I can see the execution time.

```
INSERT INTO  City  VALUES (166,'Tangail','BGD','Dhaka',106004);
```

But when I INSERT many at the same time as below I cant see the time. What is the reason for that? How can I see the execution time there too? Can somebody please help me with this.

```
INSERT INTO  City  VALUES (167,'Jamalpur','BGD','Dhaka',103556);
INSERT INTO  City  VALUES (168,'Pabna','BGD','Rajshahi',103277);
INSERT INTO  City  VALUES (169,'Naogaon','BGD','Rajshahi',101266);
INSERT INTO  City  VALUES (170,'Sirajganj','BGD','Rajshahi',99669);
INSERT INTO  City  VALUES (171,'Narsinghdi','BGD','Dhaka',98342);
INSERT INTO  City  VALUES (172,'Saidpur','BGD','Rajshahi',96777);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sadly, the answer is that phpMyAdmin (as of version 4.0.5) does not support showing execution time for multiple queries.
Note that you could do another kind of insert which would be faster and would give you execution time:

```
    INSERT INTO `City` VALUES
    (166, 'Tangail', 'BGD', 'Dhaka', 106004),
    (167, 'Jamalpur', 'BGD', 'Dhaka', 103556),
    (168, 'Pabna', 'BGD', 'Rajshahi', 103277),
    (169, 'Naogaon', 'BGD', 'Rajshahi', 101266),
    (170, 'Sirajganj', 'BGD', 'Rajshahi', 99669),
    (171, 'Narsinghdi', 'BGD', 'Dhaka', 98342),
    (172, 'Saidpur', 'BGD', 'Rajshahi', 96777);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. It is giving the execution time now. :-)

Answer (score 1):

you can use [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) for this

Comment: Thank you for the answer friend. But I cant see the answer to my question there. I have to add INSERTs to schema side there and time to build schema is not there

Comment: i thought this site has got time complexity on every query and also for bunch of queries,but i was wrong,  you can downvote

Comment: Thank you for trying to help friend :-)